# How to use DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator with GCS_Text_to_BigQuery template to Write_truncate the table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I need to use DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator with google provided GCS_Text_to_BigQuery template.
But the template has 'write_disposition' as "WRITE_APPEND", but I do not want data to be appended in BQ table, instead want to have only new data exported from every run.
How to change it to write-truncate to run using DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator  ?

I tried putting it as environment and Parameter variable but it fails to recognize it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to create a custom template using this [template source code](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#expandable-16). As noted in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#cloud-storage-text-to-bigquery):

> If you want to overwrite data in the BigQuery table instead of appending, update WriteDisposition in the template source code from WRITE_APPEND to WRITE_TRUNCATE.

Then follow these [steps](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/tree/a0cd5cde666d304ebc5e838a5c0690f59a193933#getting-started) on using Maven to build the project to staging the template file on Google Cloud Storage.

You may opt to execute the template file using [CLI tool](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/tree/a0cd5cde666d304ebc5e838a5c0690f59a193933#executing-a-template-file) or in the Google Cloud Console.